# separate files in folder according to extension python

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains a group of files with different extension like .txt , .png  , .pdf etc.

I want to organize the files and save them in different folders, for example, each file.txt in one folder and file.png in an another folder and file.pdf in an another folder etc.

```py
import os
path = r'C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\test'
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
text_files
```

In this script how can I separately move files into different folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import os
import shutil

# Note we have to escape our backslashes here
path = "C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\test\\"

for f in os.listdir(path):
    # Path to the original file
    original_file_path = os.path.join(path, f)
    # Only operate on files
    if os.path.isfile(original_file_path):
        # Get file name portion only
        file_name = os.path.basename(original_file_path)
        # Get the extension of the file and create a path for it
        extension = f.split(".")[-1]
        extension_path = os.path.join(path, extension)

        # Create the path for files with the extension if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(extension_path):
            os.makedirs(extension_path)

        # Copy the files into the new directory (copying is safer than moving, just so we can ensure it works as expected)
        shutil.copyfile(original_file_path, os.path.join(extension_path, file_name))
```

Note that this will not be clever in anyway, `.jpeg` files will go into a different folder than `.jpg` files.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
import os
import shutil


txt_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "text")
png_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "png")
pdf_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pdf")


if not os.path.isdir(txt_path):
    os.makedirs(txt_path)
    print("text folder created")
    
    
if not os.path.isdir(png_path):
    os.makedirs(png_path)
    print("png folder created")
    
    
if not os.path.isdir(pdf_path):
    os.makedirs(pdf_path)
    print("pdf folder created")
    
        

#files = ['a.png' , 'b.pdf', 'c.txt']

files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]


for file in files:
  file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)
  
  if file_path.endswith('.txt')==True:
    print('move file to text folder')
    shutil.move(file_path, txt_path)
  
  if file_path.endswith('.png')==True:
    print('move file to png folder')
    shutil.move(file_path, png_path)
  
  if file_path.endswith('.pdf')==True:
    print('move file to pdf folder')
    shutil.move(file_path, pdf_path)
```

Comment: hi Biranchi and thank you so much for help. any file with '.txt' or '.pdf' , '.png' its move perfectly but when add '.json' file nothing happen and thank you agin

Comment: mr Biranchi i am sorry the problem was from me.your code working perfectly. so appreciated